# Pandas dataframe divide column depending on value of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Currency   AmountInUSD
FR         100
US         200
JP         1000
```

What I'd like to do is, whenever we have rows where "Currency" is equal to "JP", divide its `AmountInUSD` by 100. So the result should look like this:

```
Currency   AmountInUSD
FR         100
US         200
JP         10
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Currency` is your index, you can use `iloc` to find the rows that you want to apply a transformation to :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'AmountInUSD':[100,200,1000]}, index = ['FR','US', 'JP'])

df['AmountInUSD'].iloc[df.index == 'JP']/=100
```

else just select the rows where `df.Currency == 'JP'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AmountInUSD':[100,200,1000], 'Currency': ['FR','US', 'JP']}, index = [1,2,3])
df['AmountInUSD'].loc[df.Currency == 'JP']/=100
print(df)
```

Comment: Do I need to make the currency column an index?

Comment: I assumed it was, but you don't have to ! I just edited ;)

Comment: if it is an index, this suffices : ``df.loc['JP', :] = df.loc['JP', 'AmountInUSD']/100``

Answer (score 2):

You could `mask` the Amounts corresponding to "JP" currency and replace:

```
df['AmountInUSD'] = df['AmountInUSD'].mask(df['Currency'].eq('JP'), df['AmountInUSD']/100)
```

Output:

```
  Currency  AmountInUSD
0       FR          100
1       US          200
2       JP           10
```